# Cannot find module '...' imported from '...' when trying to import functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I trying to set up a Node.js backend for an Angular app I am creating.

I got the server set up, and am now trying to call a function from a different class that will hit a third-party API.

My file structure looks as follows:

[image: Current File Structure]

My `server.js`:

```
import getTournamentData from './third-party/startgg-api-service/startgg.service'; // ERROR HAPPENING HERE
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //getTournamentData('tempest-96')
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on Port 3000');
});
```

My `startgg.service`:

```
import { startggVariables } from './startgg.variables';
import axios from 'axios';

export function getTournamentData(tourneySlug) {
    let body = getTournamentDataQuery(tourneySlug);

    axios.post(startggVariables.API_KEY, body)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
    })
}

function getTournamentDataQuery(tourneySlug) {
    let body =  { 
        "query": `
        query TournamentQuery($slug: String) {
            tournament(slug: $slug){
                id
                name
                events {
                    id
                    name
                }
            }
        }
            `,
        "operationName": "TournamentQuery",
        "variables": {"slug": tourneySlug}
    }

    return body;
}
```

My `startgg.variables`:

```
export var startggVariables = {
    API_KEY: 'https://api.start.gg/gql/alpha'
}
```

I am getting the following error when I try to run the server:

[image: Error From Building]

I have tried the relative route from the error message, I have tried importing * from that file, and I have tried export default instead of just export, but I get the same error with all.

Comment: Just add the `.js`?

Comment: I tried that as well. Did not fix the problem

Comment: Ah I see, this was the fix, but within startgg.service I also needed to add the.js there as well, so I didn't realize the first one didn't fix, as there was a second causing the same issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting the single function `getTournamentData` from `startgg.service.js`. This means you need to use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) when you import the function.

In addition, as per [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions):

> A file extension must be provided when using the import keyword to resolve relative or absolute specifiers. Directory indexes (e.g. './startup/index.js') must also be fully specified.

You should implement:

**Server.js**

```js
import { getTournamentData } from './third-party/startgg-api-service/startgg.service.js';
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
//...
```

**startgg.service.js**

```js
import { startggVariables } from './startgg.variables.js';
import axios from 'axios';
//...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
exports.getTournamentData = (tourneySlug) => {
// your code
}
```